# How to create empty normal map?

Tags: uv-image-editor, normal-map

I want to create an empty normal map , how do i do it ? The reason is because i want to paint multiple other normal map into the empty normal map .

I don't really understand how normal map works so i don't have any idea on how to create empty normal map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Head over to the [Texture Paint workspace](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/workspaces.html), click the little plus sign <kbd>+</kbd> in the *Draw* properties on the right side (Properties Editor) and select *Normal*:

[image]

This way the new normal map also gets connected to the shader, automatically. The suggested RGB values are `0.5, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0` or `#8080FF`.

[image]

Comment: ah thats why i didnt found it because i'm using blender 2.79, blender 2.8x and newer have different ui , i will try to find it on this blender version

Comment: um im sorry but can you help me ? i'm using blender 2.79 and i cant find it anywhere , maybe this is a new feature on 2.8 or newer ?

Comment: @user6668201 I don't have access to 2.79 anymore. I guess this was introduced as of 2.8x

Comment: Tried to download 2.79 but I can't get it to work properly (high dpi display) @user6668201 If I have access to it, I'll update my answer.

Comment: ah its okay , i'm not in any way forcing you to answer , i still can just wait for other people  and use my method in the meanwhile

Comment: @user6668201 It's nearly the same in 2.79, set the mode to texture paint and you can create a new paint slot. You just have to set the color to R 0.5, G 0.5 and B 1.0 otherwise you'll get a black map. Updated my answer so you can set the proper values by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind i found the answer
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31557/why-arent-tangent-space-normal-maps-completely-blue
Turns out normal map default color is RGB(128,128,255) , but blender is using 0-1 scale for rgb so converting from scale 0-255 produce some decimal inaccuracy , instead use the hex value for RGB(128,128,255) which is #8080FF

All i need to do is to put the default color value to the color when creating new image
[image]

Comment: There is an built-in way: Head over to the texture paint workspace, click the little plus sign in the draw properties on the right side and select "Normal".

Comment: oh really ? can you just answer it instead of in this comment ? if there is really built in way to do it then it is a better method since there is no inaccuracy due to conversion

Comment: you can use *Hex* instead of *RGB* and enter 8080FF

Comment: AH YOU RIGHT !!!!!! i searched on RGB to hex converter  on web search that accept 0-255 scale , and it gives me precise hex value for it , thanks !!!!!

Comment: i have edited my answer to change it from using rgb to hex , no more decimal inaccuracy , thankss